# Why will the scripts on this view not run

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an expandable input table and I am running into some issues. Both seem to be related to the fact that the scripts are not running, but I am not sure. None of the buttons are working even though they have in the past. I don't know what changed, but I did not change the add or delete functions but they don't work anymore. The submit button doesn't seem to trigger the corresponding function in the controller.

I have tried looking for syntax errors and there don't seem to be any. The scripts seem to be referencing the correct portion of the view.

Here is the controller:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Promotion_Generator.Models.DataModels;

namespace Promotion_Generator.Controllers
{
    public class PromotionController : Controller
    {
        private PromotionGeneratorEntities db = new PromotionGeneratorEntities();

        public ActionResult BOGO()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult BOGOSave(string BuyMemberData, string GetMemberData)
        {
            try
            {
                var BuySerializeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(BuyMemberData);

                foreach (var data in BuySerializeData)
                {

                }

                var GetSerializeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(GetMemberData);


                foreach (var data in GetSerializeData)
                {

                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json("fail");
            }

            return Json("success");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the View

```
@model Promotion_Generator.Models.BOGOModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BOGO";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2><b>Buy One Get One Free</b></h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class = "control-label col-md-2"><b>Promotion Code</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PROMOTION_CODE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PROMOTION_CODE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Description</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Start Date Time</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.START_DATE_TIME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.START_DATE_TIME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>End Date Time</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.END_DATE_TIME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.END_DATE_TIME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Percent Off</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PERCENT_OFF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PERCENT_OFF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Percent Off</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BUY_MEMBERS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PERCENT_OFF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <h3><b>Buy Products</b></h3>
            <table id="buyProducts" class="table">
                <thread>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <p>Product UPC</p>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thread>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.BUY_MEMBERS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="T1Remove(this)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd1" type="button" name="name" value="Add" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <h3><b>Get Products</b></h3>
            <table id="getProducts" class="table">
                <thread>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <p>Product UPC</p>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thread>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.GET_MEMBERS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="T2Remove(this)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd2" type="button" name="name" value="Add" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Index", "Home")
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(".btnAdd1").click(function () {
            //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
            var tBody = $("#buyProducts > TBODY")[0];

            //Add Row.
            var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

            //Add Editor cell.
            var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
            cell.append("@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.GET_MEMBERS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })");

            //Add Button cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
            var btnRemove = $("<input />");
            btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
            btnRemove.attr("onclick", "T1Remove(this);");
            btnRemove.val("Remove");
            cell.append(btnRemove);

            //Clear the TextBoxes.
            txtName.val("");
            txtCountry.val("");
        });
        $(".btnAdd2").click(function () {
            //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
            var tBody = $("#getProducts > TBODY")[0];

            //Add Row.
            var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

            //Add Editor cell.
            var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
            cell.append("@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.GET_MEMBERS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })");

            //Add Button cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
            var btnRemove = $("<input />");
            btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
            btnRemove.attr("onclick", "T2Remove(this);");
            btnRemove.val("Remove");
            cell.append(btnRemove);

            //Clear the TextBoxes.
            txtName.val("");
            txtCountry.val("");
        });
        function T1Remove(button) {
            //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
            var row = $(button).closest("TR");
            var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
                //Get the reference of the Table.
                var table = $("#buyProducts")[0];

                //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
                table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
            }
        };
        function T2Remove(button) {
            //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
            var row = $(button).closest("TR");
            var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
                //Get the reference of the Table.
                var table = $("#getProducts")[0];

                //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
                table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
            }
        };
        function BuyMembers() {
            var BuyMembers = $(this).find('#BuyMembers').val();
            return BuyMembers;
        };
        function GetMembers() {
            var GetMembers = $(this).find('#GetMembers').val();
            return GetMembers;
        };
        $('.btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Promotion/SaveData',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(BuyMembers),
                data: JSON.stringify(GetMembers),
                success: function () {
                    alert("Data Added Successfully");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while inserting data");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

When I hit the Add, Remove, and Submit buttons the script doesn't seem to run and no columns are added or deleted.

Comment: Are you getting errors in your browsers console?

Comment: There is an error on line 187 of the view saying that the line is missing a closing parenthesis. I don't see where it should go or what the problem is.

Comment: Which line is line 187?  SO doesn't have line numbers.

Comment: Sorry, That is the line that says "cell.append("@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.GET_MEMBERS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })");"

Comment: I figured out that problem though. I accidentally used double quotes instead of single quotes. I am still having issues with adding and submiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently assigning the jQuery events to the classes (`$(".btnAdd1")`) instead of ids (`$("#btnAdd1")`). You can either change your events to link to the id values:

```
$("#btnAdd1").click(function () {
    //...
}

$("#btnAdd2").click(function () {
    //...
});

$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    //...
});
```

or change the inputs to have the classes of the events. This will fix your issue with the click events not triggering.

Comment: Thanks so much. I totally missed this.